# Is there an adverb meaning “now, but not in the past”?

Tags: single-word-requests, adverbs, time

“Still” means “in the past and now”: “It is still raining.”

Is there an English adverb meaning “now, but not in the past”?

Comment: You could say *"it has just started raining."* But I don't believe there's a single-word adverb for this. (Except maybe the non-standard [*"positive anymore"*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29269/what-are-the-possible-meanings-of-positive-any-more), which is not appropriate for "it's raining" even in dialects that use it.)

Comment: I wasa about to say the same thing when I read your comment, Peter. Positive _any()more_ seems to be limited to situations of longer term, either stative or generic: _It rains a lot in the winter anymore_, but not **It's raining anymore*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Now](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Now)  (adverb)

> - At the present time.

- It is raining now.

Comment: You can also use `right now` to completely remove all references to other times. E.g. `It's raining right now`.

Answer (score 2):

It is ***currently*** raining connotes it is raining now with no reference to the past.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest *presently*.

*It is presently raining* doesn't completely rule out past or future rain; however, I would argue that the fact you have chosen to emphasise that it is raining **now** does at least imply that there is some sort of contrast - whether that be with past or future.