# Why does "broad" not rhyme with "boat"?

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling, historical-change, vowels, old-english

The word "broad" is pronounced /br**ɔː**d/ (some US accents: /br**ɑː**d/) instead of */br**əʊ**d/. The spelling **-OA-** somehow suggests that these words are closely related and/or were pronounced the same at some point. In simple words, *broad* rhymes with *caught, thought, sought* and doesn't rhyme with BOAT, COAT, LOATH, ROAD, FOAM etc.

"[Broad](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/broad)" is from [Old English](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/brad#Old_English) **brād** and its Old English pronunciation was /brɑːd/.

It seems that ***[boat](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bat#Old_English), [road](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rad#Old_English), [loath](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/la%C3%BE#Old_English), [foam](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fam#Old_English)*** and ***[broad](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/brad#Old_English)*** had the same vowel sound **/ɑː/** in Old English. All of them were spelled with **ā** and Wikitionary notes that their pronunciations were with **/ɑː/** vowel. Why then is *broad* not pronounced the same as all those other words?

#### Edit

About a week ago I was reading a book on [internet archive](https://archive.org/) (whose name I have forgotten now and I am unable to find it again) which had an entry on "broad" and "abroad". I was lucky enough to take and save a screenshot from the entry. But I do not understand it well.

[image]

Comment: The major reasons are (1) that not all sound changes occur without exceptions. And (2) that English spelling does not represent the sounds of Modern English.

Comment: @JohnLawler That's utterly true! English spelling doesn't make sense but I'm sure someone here knows *why it happened* and that's what I'm interested in knowing. ;-)

Comment: I would disagree that most Americans have the FATHER vowel in *broad* instead of the THOUGHT vowel. That would sound bizarre, and you'd notice it right off the bat sticking out like a sore thumb.

Comment: @tchrist I dont know but Cambridge English dictionary only lists the FATHER vowel for most words in American English. I'll edit it.

Comment: @Sphinx They're making things up because their sample size of N=1 is some junior high school kid from West Hollywood. Most of the country doesn't speak that way, but Hollywood has an outsized representation in foreigners' perceptions.

Comment: The /a/ ~ /ɔ/ distinction in American English is pretty much absent in younger speakers any more. It used to be present east of the Mississippi but now it's often hard to tell the difference between _Dawn_ and _Don_, or _caught_ and _cot_ in most people's speech.

Comment: @JohnLawler Did you really just use [positive *anymore* like a Pittsburgher](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/377705/2085)?

Comment: It's not that regional. I grew up with it in N. Illinois.

Comment: @herisson I have got another question though. Would you be able to have a look at it? https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/559604/why-does-the-diphthong-a%ca%8a-not-occur-before-k-m-p-b-g-etc

Comment: @JohnLawler Interesting. I actually grew up just a few miles from where you did, but don't much remember it. But I led a somewhat sheltered childhood with book-blinders on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pronunciation of *broad* with /ɔː/ instead of /əʊ/ is exceptional. Most words spelled with *oa* followed by a letter other than "r" are pronounced with /əʊ/ (/oʊ/ in American English), which developed regularly from Middle English /ɔː/. A previous question asking whether there are any similar examples of *oa* being pronounced /ɔː/ turned up no similar words: [Is the pronunciation of "oa" in "broad" unique?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/240233/is-the-pronunciation-of-oa-in-broad-unique)

There is not a clear reason for *broad* not being pronounced /brəʊd/. As the extract you quote mentions, it is possible that the use of /ɔː/ is related to the *r* in this word, but that's not a perfect explanation because there are other words with r such as *road, broke, groan* that have /əʊ/ and not /ɔː/ in modern English.

*[Great, break, steak](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36188/why-is-great-pronounced-as-grate-but-spelled-with-ea)* are similar exceptions to the usual development of /iː/ in words with the Middle English vowel [ɛː] and the modern English spelling pattern *-ea-*.