# “Chris Christie may have move to the right” - Isn’t it a typo?

Tags: grammaticality

Washington Post (November 7) carries the article titled, “Democrats begin effort to negatively define Chris Christie before 2016 campaign.” with a caption of video:

> Gov. Chris Christie may be eyeing a 2016 presidential run, but he **may
>   have move to** the right if he wants to appeal to the Republican base.
>   Sabrina Schaeffer and Richard Fowler discuss.

http://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/democrats-begin-effort-to-negatively-define-chris-christie-before-2016-campaign/2013/11/06/780e4420-4720-11e3-bf0c-cebf37c6f484_story.html?wpisrc=nl_most

I cut and pasted the above quote from Washington Post’s online text.

Shouldn’t it be “he may have **to** move to the right”? Is it a simple typo, or acceptable as a journalism parlance?

Comment: You are correct, but this is just proof reading.

Comment: @Jim. I guessed so. But it’s very unlikely you find a typo in leading newspapers and magazines in our country (though we find erroneous reports of the fact from time to time). Proof-check department is an essential part of press, and press hire a troop of proof-readers. So I wasn’t very sure whether it’s a typo or intended phrasing.

Comment: It's actually becoming more common in web versions, from what I have seen. Preparation times have been compressed for immediate release on the web, whereas most print articles have scheduled releases. Frankly, it surprises me when they simply get the facts right any more.

Comment: @Jim: a use of the [positive any more](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10206/should-anymore-only-be-used-in-a-negative-statement-or-question).

Comment: Ha! I knew the moment I wrote that it would get someone's attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very likely a typo; the only way I can see it being correct is if *move* is regarded as a noun, something meaning "leeway" or "give." Even then it doesn't make sense in the context of the sentence.