# Is the use of the positive "anymore" considered correct?

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality, dialects, non-standard

While the word *anymore* is usually a negative context, the [positive *anymore*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_anymore) is a well-documented phenomenon. I found this surprising, because I had never come across the positive *anymore* in a conversational or written context before. I consulted Bryan M. Garner's *Dictionary of Modern American Usage*, which seemed to suggest that the positive use of *anymore* can be considered correct.

My question to you: is the positive use of *anymore* considered correct spoken/standard written English?

Comment: Nope, it is not. I have heard *any more* used in this way, and I always have to think twice before I "oh, that". Note also that standard spelling is two words, with a space: perhaps not using a space in the positive use could be used to mark it as such?

Comment: @Cerberus Standard spelling by which standards? British? Spelling *anymore* as one word is commonplace in American English.

Comment: I've never heard it used this way. The two examples that Wikipedia article gives of positive-anymore used in American utterances would be much more idiomatically expressed using *Anyway, ...* where I'm from. The Irish ones are difficult to impossible for me to parse. I'm not even sure what the word "*anymore*" is trying to express in the Canadian example; something like "nowadays" or "these days" maybe?

Comment: @DanBron The Canadian example uses "anymore" synonymously with "lately."

Comment: @Cerberus: while the standard *anymore* can be spelled with [one or two words](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/any-more-also-anymore?q=any+more), I would really encourage spelling the positive *anymore* with one word. because (1) this spelling is preferred in the U.S., and the positive *anymore* is predominantly an American construction and (2) the positive *anymore* doesn't make any sense if you try to unpack it into two words.

Comment: @Dan Bron: What the positive *anymore* means is: we didn't use to, but now we do. I am willing to bet the Canadian example means: *"lately but not earlier"* (which is what *"lately"* would ordinarily mean here, but it's not always what *"lately"* means).

Comment: @PeterShor  If I had taken the time to read the introductory material in the WP article, rather than jumping directly to the examples, I wouldn't have been so confused. All is clear now. I suppose, to know whether this construction is still used, we need a Midwesterner to chime in. I'm a Northeast guy.

Comment: @DanBron It's fairly common, or at least understood, in the upper Midwest. My wife finds it grating and would never use it, but has no trouble grasping what it means.

Comment: @JimMack That's so interesting! I find it *completely* disorienting. When I hit it in those sentences, I was thrown for a loop! I had no idea what was going on.

Comment: It's a dialectal feature, and quite common. No grammar problems with it, but many people don't speak that dialect. The only difference is that _any more_ is not a negative polarity item and therefore can occur without a licensing negative. Rather like saying _I have ever been there_; disorienting. But for people who speak this dialect, _any more_ simply means _nowadays_, and it implies there has been a change of state, just like NPI _any more_; it's just not presupposed to be a negative change. So my mother (born 1914, Clinton, IA) could say _I take all my cleaning there any more_.

Comment: @DanBron Interesting -- I thought that the use of the positive anymore was primarily a southern-ism.

Comment: @JohnLawler I wonder if it's possible to use *anymore* to construct a sentence which means different things to speakers of different dialects. Like a verbal version of the blue-dress/gold-dress optical illusion. Anyway, your comment is worthy of conversion to an answer. (And even though I now *know* what it means, your mom's use of "any more" in that sentence *still* momentarily confused me. It's really hard for me to make it mean what I know it means.)

Comment: Closely related: [Should “anymore” only be used in a negative statement or question?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10206)

Comment: I didn't know  "anymore" to mean "nowadays" was limited to certain regions.  I've heard it my whole life in the Midwest, but it reminds me of my grandmother.  It feels old-fashioned to me.  I would only use it to write a quote or dialogue of someone saying it.  It seems too informal to me for written use.

Comment: @Palizsche the other questions is a duplicate; this one is nearly two years older.

Comment: @Newb, sorry about that! I removed my comment.  Obviously, I didn't look closely at the dates!

Comment: Please give examples of the standard usage -and- this non-standard 'positive' use. You can't assume that the link will stay there forever - the question text should be self-contained.

Answer (score 4):

Here is what Bryan Garner, *Garner's Modern American Usage*, second edition (2003) says about *anymore* used in the sense of "nowadays":

> **anymore. A. Meaning "now."** In the sense "now," "nowadays," or "still," the word *anymore* fits in three contexts: (1) negative declaratives {you don't bring me flowers anymore}, (2) yes–no questions {Do you go there anymore?}, and (3) hypothetical clauses introduced by *whether* or *if* {I wonder whether they go there anymore}. In sense 1, the meaning is "now" or "nowadays"; in senses 2 and 3, the meaning is "still." When *anymore* is used in some other type of positive statement (not in sense 2 or 3), it is dialectal—e.g., "The price of housing is outrageous *anymore* {read *these days* or *nowadays*}." In a [1986] linguistic study of Missourians, informants considered this dialectal usage "well established though controversial." [Citation omitted.] That mans that the informants were all familiar with it, but many didn't like it. The findings would probably hold throughout most of the United States.

Garner notes that *anymore* is standard in U.S. English when it appears in negative constructions ("Don't do X anymore"), in questions ("are they X anymore?"), and in hypotheticals ("whether we X anymore"). But in positive declarative statements such as "People are rude anymore," Garner holds (accurately, in my opinion) that the usage is not standard across U.S. English, but dialectal.

The form of expression has been around for a long time, as is evident from these examples reported in Harold Wentworth, *American Dialect Dictionary* (1944):

> **1903 s.e.Penn[sylvania] Lancaster Co[unty]** There's just only this one any more. Martin 'Ellie's Furnishing.' ... **1929 Iowa** 'Any more I don't like the boughten [ice cream].' Characteristic. K. Buxbaum. **1930s w.cent.W[est] V[irginia] Charleston** We still use that custom anymore. **1931 s.w.Penn[sylvania]** It's quite warm anymore..It's pretty poor anymore..Anymore I never see him. ... **1932 cent.Ill[inois] Dewitt Co[unty]** 'We used to go to Weldon Springs for picnics, but any more we go to Salt Creek.'Common. C. W. Carter, Jr. ...

Although Wentworth indicates that Northern Appalachia (West Virginia, Pennsylvania, Maryland, and Kentucky) is the primary locus of such usage, he also finds instances from New York, Ohio, South Carolina, Kansas, southern Ontario, Michigan, Montana, and (as noted above) Iowa and Illinois. The examples of dialectal *any more* in *American Dialect Dictionary*, despite being set in small type, come close to filling two print pages. Still, notwithstanding such wide distribution, the expression remains dialectal—and Wentworth reports no instances from New England, the Pacific states, much of the interior West, the Southwest, and much of the South.

So the answer to your question "is the positive use of *anymore* considered correct spoken/standard written English?" seems to be that it may be considered so by English speakers for whom the dialectal use is natural, but not by others. And as Garner remarks, even in areas (such as Missouri) where the usage is currently familiar to many people, "many didn't like it."

Comment: Your first quote says that in negative declaratives, the meaning is ***now*** or ***nowadays***. I really don't think that's precise enough; many sentences that work with *nowadays* don't work with *anymore*: *"Although they were predicted in multitudinous science fiction movies of the 20th  century, we don't have flying cars anymore."*

Comment: @PeterShor: I'm pretty sure that Garner would agree with you on that point. My sense is that he is saying that _anymore_ can function nondialectally in the sense of "now, nowadays, or still" in certain situations involving (for example) negative constructions—but that doesn't mean that _anymore_ is interchangeable with every acceptable instance of one of those words in a negative construction. Thus, we can say "You still haven't answered my question" in standard English, but not "You anymore haven't answered my question."

Comment: I'm pretty sure he would, too. But that's a mistake that people not used to positive anymore make when they think it is a synonym of *nowadays*. In most dialects which have it, it means *now, but not earlier*. (I say *most* because there might be exceptions, although I haven't encountered any.)

Comment: @PeterShor: That's a very interesting definition. I applied it to the many examples in Wentworth's _American Dialect Dictionary, and found only one instance where that definition clearly doesn't prevail—in the 1930s Charleston, West Va. quotation, "We still use that custom anymore." A 1935 citation from Elmira, N.Y., offers this translation, which matches the definition you give: "'I like that anymore' = Now I like it; formerly I did not or was in doubt. 'We go there all the time anymore,' 'We do that any more' = We go, & do, now but did not formerly." ...

Comment: ... On the other hand, a 1939 citation from Huntington, West Va. says this: "Chiefly spoken. More rural than urban. Very common. Quite spontaneous. Not the opposite of _not any more_. Does not necessarily imply that the opposite was formerly true." It thus seems that the expression could be used in different ways in different locales, including (often) "now but not earlier" and (sometimes) "now and perhaps also in the past." I have never lived in a place where this way of using _anymore_ was common, so the fine points of its usage are a mystery to me.

Answer (score 0):

The reasons are specifically because of the niche "anymore" plays in speech.  We have more popular adverbs that serve the positive definition: nowadays, typically, usually, normally.

The use of anymore is certainly common to midwestern (spoken) dialects and would certainly be correct.  But as with anything dialectical, it's best to use a more broadly accepted alternative in speech anymore...

Answer (score 0):

I would say (as all expert references do) that it's "incorrect" to use "anymore" in a positive (versus negative) construction. But it does occur in regional dialect (I had a friend from Massillon, Ohio who used it positively, as if she'd never heard the word "nowadays".) 
A similar one is "might could be" for "maybe"...an obvious redundancy, but one that people do use, particularly in the southern U.S. Another from the same region is the use of "coke" for any soft drink, as in, "I'll have an orange coke."

Comment: I have heard "coke" used as a blanket term for soft drinks; but I have never heard anyone ask for an "orange coke." Maybe something more like, "Let's go have some cokes; I'll have an orange pop."

Comment: @DavidBowling Yup, say "orange coke" anymore and you will be laughed at. (which isn't the *any more* in "you're out of orange soda, do you have any more in the back?". And Geem, as far as I know, alls us that use *might could be* also use *maybe*. We jus got maybe 20 more modals, and that was some hard doin'. We's sure not about to go and lose any.

Answer (score -1):

I've always thought there's a distinct difference between "any more" (two words) and "anymore" (one word), illustrated by the following sentence: "I'm sorry, we don't have **any more** widgets, because the company doesn't make them **anymore**."  The single word "anymore" is strictly a temporal adverb.

Comment: I'm not sure you understood that question asked about the use of "anymore" to mean"nowadays".  Example: "Anymore, we stay home and watch Netflix instead of going out to the movies."  It's Midwestern U.S. dialect.  Not everyone uses "anymore" this way.  The question is asking whether this usage is considered correct standard English.