# Why have Americans started reversing the term 'anymore'?

Tags: american-english, negative-polarity-items

Here's an example: Someone who is attempting to say "I don't see any people wearing blue jumpers anymore" will instead say "I see people wearing blue jumpers anymore".

I'm referring to online comments exclusively. I've never heard anyone actually use this terminology in real life.

This usage appears to have begun relatively recently. Why? It appears to be an American style.

Comment: Americans seem to do this. They start with a meaningful idiomatic phrase then start to omit words from it until it is nonsensical. A good example is "I couldn't care less what he thinks" which has been turned into "I could care less what he thinks" and therefore has its meaning reversed but is still used for its original purpose. Another example is "I went through it with a fine-tooth comb" which has been turned into "I went through it with a tooth comb". All combs have teeth so a tooth comb sounds like something used for dental care. Your sentence is another example.

Comment: @BoldBen It's a mildly annoying, yet somewhat charming, trait of Americans.

Comment: So you think they meant the sentence with the "not" in it? Are you sure that's what they meant? Isn't it more likely that they meant the sentence without a "not" -- as they said -- and that it's the "any more" that's unusual? See https://english.stackexchange.com/q/240290 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/377705

Comment: Lumping all Americans together is a little harsh.  :-)  I’ve never heard this. And hope I never do.

Comment: @Jim Oh, please don't get me wrong, mate. I certainly don't mean most Americans at all.

Comment: Linguists have studied "positive anymore" and found that it occurs predominantly in parts of the midwest and the east. Check out the Yale Grammatical Diversity Project for more information and a map of sitings. No doubt migration from that region accounts for its current presence in California. We've found it in both Merced and Redding. https://web.stanford.edu/dept/linguistics/VoCal/grammar.shtml#:~:text=%22Anymore%20my%20kids%20live%20far%20away.%22&text=The%20difference%20is%20simply%20that,the%20midwest%20and%20the%20east.

Comment: @user66974 That's fascinating. And thank you very much. A note: if you ever feel inclined to write that as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: I want to read these comments anymore.

Comment: You attribute the wrong meaning to your example. What *"People are wearing blue jumpers anymore"* means is *"People didn't use to wear blue jumpers, but now they've started doing it."* If we want to say they used to wear blue jumpers, but have stopped, we would say *"I don't see people wearing blue jumpers anymore,"* just like the rest of the English-speaking world.

Comment: @PeterShor With respect, man, I think you're a bit mixed up there.

Comment: @MathsBarry Charming, lel (I'm admittedly assuming 'lel and 'lol' are allowed here).

Comment: Just so we're clear, "I could care less" is everyday sarcasm for *I couldn't care less*: Yeah, like I could care less (= which I couldn't)! See also *Like I give a sh!t.* Here to say that **online** standards, except here, are not high anymore.

Comment: @White Prime: I am American, and I don't believe I have ever heard anybody misuse *anymore* the way you think we Americans misuse it. When we misuse *anymore*, you can generally replace it by *nowadays*. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_anymore).

Comment: I suppose it's vaguely possible that  the people you see misusing *anymore* online are non-Americans who have picked up the idea of misusing *anymore* from Americans, but are misusing it wrong.

Comment: @PeterShor With due respect, man, have you seen user 66974's comment in this very thread?

Comment: @White Prime. Did you even look at the [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_anymore) I put in my comment for positive anymore? Wikipedia claims that it means *nowadays* or *from now on*. But feel free not to  believe either Wikipedia or me.

Comment: @PeterShor Interesting.