# What does “any longer” mean when it falls in the middle of the sentence instead of at the end?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, adverbials, negative-polarity-items, negative-concord

The bold part of this sentence is extremely hard for me to understand:

> There is also a tendency to imply a crisis to which one goes and then in some way retreats from. **Now I can’t see that crisis any longer means a climax**, unless we are willing to grant that every breath of wind has a climax(which I am) (...)
>
> —from [Space, Time and Dance by Merce Cunningham](https://www.mercecunningham.org/the-work/writings/space-time-and-dance/)

Does it mean

a) *Crisis* means a *climax* to the author,

or

b) Crisis doesn't mean climax to the author any longer?

Or maybe it's neither of those two.

The examples sentences on [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/any%20longer) are easy to understand because there *any longer* is at the end of the sentences. However, I don't understand what it means in the quoted sentence, where it is not at the end. What does it mean there?

Comment: It's 'b'; adverbs and what some termed 'adverbials' can be fairly labile in a sentence.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Now there’s a word you don’t get to use everyday.

Comment: _Any longer_ is a Negative Polarity Item. That means its use is not determined by where it is in a sentence, but by where it is relative to the negative trigger that licenses it. And _can('t) see_ is a neg-raising verb, so it actually means _I can see that crisis no longer means climax_.

Comment: Related [Should "anymore" be used only in a negative statement or question?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10206), [What are the possible meanings of positive "any more"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29269), [Is the use of the positive "anymore" considered correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/240290).

Comment: @jsw29 The funny thing is that this isn't a positive use of something that's normally only used in negatives like those two questions you cite do. This one is still a normal negative use.

Comment: @Jim 'Motile' is probably more helpful. _Nomadic_?

Comment: The sentence is poorly written and would tend to confuse many people.

Comment: If ***any longer*** comes at the end of the utterance, it's a ***whole sentence adverb*** usage: the entire (non-negated) assertion *I **can** see that crisis means a climax* is no longer true (by implication, it ***was*** previously true; that's what I thought). I'd say in practice the same applies to ***Now*** at the *other* end of the sentence (*now* the entire following assertion ***is*** true, though previously it ***wasn't*** true).

Answer (score 1):

The usage in question uses *any longer* right before a finite verb instead of at the end of the entire sentence:

> Now I can’t see that crisis **any longer** means a climax, unless we are willing to grant that every breath of wind has a climax (which I am) (...)

That is saying that for the writer, a crisis ***no longer*** means a climax as it perhaps once may have. It doesn’t mean that ***anymore***.  Or simply that it does ***not still*** mean that. So one simple way to look at the meaning of this use of *any longer* is by swapping it for the adverb *still*:

> Now I can’t see that crisis **still** means a climax, unless we are willing to grant that every breath of wind has a climax (which I am) (...)
> That has the same meaning as the original.

The OED describes this sense under its section on the idiomatic phrases of the adverb *long* [in this (paywalled) way](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/109979):

> ### P3. Idiomatic phrases.
>
> - **d.** ***no* (also *not any*) *longer***: not from the point specified or implied, in contrast with the situation at an earlier time; (also, in stronger sense) never again. Cf. sense 2b, and *no more* adv. 1a, 1b.

They provide examples from the past two centuries that include these, where I’ve added bold to make it easier to see the demonstrated use:

> - 1841   T. Carlyle *On Heroes* vi. 327
>      Nature..was as if effete now; could **not any longer** produce Great Men.
> - 1894   H. Caine *Manxman* ɪɪɪ. xix. 190
>      There was **no longer any** room for doubt.
> - 1959   *Life 8 June* 156/2
>      He admitted that once there had been some [slave labor camps] but **not any longer**.
> - 2005   *Computer Buyer* May (Compl. Guide to Media Center Suppl.) 20/3
>      One of today’s hot topics among future-gazers is whether TV programmes will **no longer** be broadcast over the airwaves.

The sense 2b which they reference there is this:

> 2. **b.** In comparative, chiefly with adverbs or adverbial phrases indicating degree, as *any, no, much, a little*, etc.: after the specified or implied point in time.

That’s probably more like what you’re used to seeing. It’s a sense closely related to the one that puzzled you.
This one is just like *no longer* but becomes *any longer* under negative concord.
They provide citations for it like:

> - **1975**   B. Donoughue Diary 25 June in *Downing St. Diary* (2005) xvii. 431
>      It is clear that this Prime Minister should **not** go on **much longer**.
> - **2011**   T. Wakefield *Knuckler* ix. 155
>      The 2003 Red Sox had too much at stake for the experiment to continue **any longer**.

Your example used *any* because it was in a negative context, governed by *can’t see*. Outside negative contexts that therefore require *any* for negative concord, you would instead use *no longer* directly:

1. I do **not** plan to stay **any longer** than my wife does.
2. I plan to stay **no longer** than my wife does.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I had difficulty understanding that at first too, but try separating "any longer," from the rest of the sentence.

> Now I can’t see that crisis any longer means a climax, unless we are willing to grant that every breath of wind has a climax(which I am) (...)

—from Space, Time and Dance by Merce Cunningham (Original)

They could have meant that they no longer see a crisis as the climax.

> I [no longer feel that crisis means] climax, unless we are willing to grant that every breath of wind has a climax(which I am) (...)

—from Space, Time and Dance by Merce Cunningham (Edited)

Does that make more sense? For example, a situation where a squirrel runs into the road in front of the car. The climax would be right before the squirrel is hit, and the crisis would be when the squirrel is hit. The author could mean that they see the two objects as separate and that they didn't before. I hope this makes sense!

-Lilith Hope